# I wrote a simple python game but functions in that are not executing

Tags: python, function

I am fairly new in python coding. I made a simple rock, paper, scissor game using **random** module. I wrote it in three functions. when I am executing it, I get no error but it is not executing the functions.

what I wrote:

```
import random

def main():
     global comp
     global user
     global play

     play = ''

     #preparing list for computer to select from
     game = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']

     #computer chooses randomly from the list above
     comp = random.choice(game)
     print(comp)

     #user inputs their choice
     user = input("Rock, Paper or Scissor? ")

def user_choice():
     global play
     play = input("Do you want to continue? press y or n for yes and no respectively. ")

     if play == y:
         main()
     elif play == n:
         print("Thank you for playing!")
         exit()

 #conditions to the game
def play_game():
     global user
     global comp

     while True:    
        if user == comp:
           print("Tie!")
           print("Computer: ", comp, "and User:", user)

        elif user == 'rock':
            if comp == 'paper':
               print("Rock covers paper, computer wins")

            else:
               print("rock smashes through scissor, you win")

        elif user == 'paper':
            if comp == 'rock':
               print("paper covers rock, you win!")

            else:
               print("scissor cuts through paper, computer wins")

        elif user == 'scissor':
            if comp == 'rock':
               print("Rock smashes through scissor, Computer wins!")

            else:
               print("Scissor cuts through paper")

       user_choice()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

play_game()
```

it is not executing play_game() and user_choice().
It only ask for the input.

Comment: Also `play == y` should be `play == "y"`. same goes for `elif play == "n":`

Comment: as a side note, declaring `global variables` are considered to be bad practice. put them in the main body makes them global. Its part of python scoping and a shared feature in many languages.

Comment: On second thought, [It works fine for me](https://imgur.com/a/ZfvCkfh). After making the changes I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing which is wrong is that y and n are not under "" thus python is treating them as a variable. the second thing which was wrong is the position of the play game which should come below the main() to get executed. All user_choice() was not indented properly
Try this code

```
import random


def main():
     global comp
     global user
     global play

     play = ''

     # preparing list for computer to select from
     game = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']

     # computer chooses randomly from the list above
     comp = random.choice(game)
     print(comp)

     # user inputs their choice
     user = input("Rock, Paper or Scissor? ")


def user_choice():
     global play
     play = input(
         "Do you want to continue? press y or n for yes and no respectively. ")

     if play == "y":
         main()
     elif play == "n":
         print("Thank you for playing!")
         exit()

 # conditions to the game


def play_game():
     global user
     global comp

     while True:
        if user == comp:
           print("Tie!")
           print("Computer: ", comp, "and User:", user)

        elif user == 'rock':
            if comp == 'paper':
               print("Rock covers paper, computer wins")

            else:
               print("rock smashes through scissor, you win")

        elif user == 'paper':
            if comp == 'rock':
               print("paper covers rock, you win!")

            else:
               print("scissor cuts through paper, computer wins")

        elif user == 'scissor':
            if comp == 'rock':
               print("Rock smashes through scissor, Computer wins!")

            else:
               print("Scissor cuts through paper")

        user_choice()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    play_game()
```

Comment: Same result. Still not executing

Comment: @omsinghml You need to share more details otherwise no one can help you. Your code works fine with some modifications I commented earlier.

Comment: it works on my system. Have you tested a basic `helloworld()` function first and an confirm that works ?

Comment: I corrected my mistake with `play == "y"` and `play =="n"`. I called `play_game()` and `user_choice` function under main() but its still getting me the same [result](https://i.imgur.com/mNUeRoh.png).

Comment: yes my helloworld() function is working @D.L

Comment: good,  then copy parts of code and paste into the same hello world and tell us where it fails. It should then be obvious where it works or fails.

Comment: This code should work on your machine if it does not work please try some online compiler and try to run it there.

Comment: Code works in different complier. Thankyou all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The code calls the `main()` function and this takes an input, but it does not call any of the other functions.

This is why.

Expect that you mean to call `play_game()` and `user_choice()` from within `main()`.

Working code.

```
import random

def main():
     global comp
     global user
     global play

     play = ''

     #preparing list for computer to select from
     game = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']

     #computer chooses randomly from the list above
     comp = random.choice(game)
     print(comp)

     #user inputs their choice
     user = input("Rock, Paper or Scissor? ")

     user_choice()
     play_game()
     

def user_choice():
     global play
     play = input("Do you want to continue? press y or n for yes and no respectively. ")

     if play == 'y':
         main()
     elif play == 'n':
         print("Thank you for playing!")
         exit()

#conditions to the game
def play_game():
     global user
     global comp

     while True:    
        if user == comp:
           print("Tie!")
           print("Computer: ", comp, "and User:", user)

        elif user == 'rock':
            if comp == 'paper':
               print("Rock covers paper, computer wins")

            else:
               print("rock smashes through scissor, you win")

        elif user == 'paper':
            if comp == 'rock':
               print("paper covers rock, you win!")

            else:
               print("scissor cuts through paper, computer wins")

        elif user == 'scissor':
            if comp == 'rock':
               print("Rock smashes through scissor, Computer wins!")

            else:
               print("Scissor cuts through paper")


       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: still the same result, not executing the function

Answer (score 0):

Create another function main() and call play_game() and user_choice() within main.